# SqlQuery and SqlFieldsQuery

Tags: ignite

it looks that SqlQuery only supports sql that starts with `select *`? Doesn't it support other sql that only select some columns like
`select id, name from person` and maps the columns to the corresponding POJO?

If I use SqlFieldQuery to run sql, the result is a QueryCursor of List(each List contains one record of the result). But if the sql starts with `select *`,  the this list's contents would be different with field query like:
`select id,name,age from person`

For the `select *`, each List is constructed with 3 parts:

1. the first elment is the key of the cache
2. the second element is the pojo object that contains the data
3. the tailing element are the values for each column.

Why was it so designed? If I don't know what the sql that SqlFieldsQuery runs , then I need additional effort to figure out what the List contains.

Comment: Tom, there a same tickets in IGNITE JIRA. For example: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3466  As a workaround you can specify list of columns and do not use star symbol.

Comment: Thanks @kuaw26. It is another case that the first two columns that `select *` return is K and V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlQuery` returns key and value objects, while `SqlFieldsQuery` allows to select specific fields. Which one to use depends on your use case.

Currently `select *` indeed includes predefined `_key` and `_val` fields, and this will be improved in the future. However, generally it's a good practice to list fields you want to fetch when running SQL queries (this is true for any SQL database, not only Ignite). This way your code will be protected from unexpected behavior in case schema is changed, for example.